# How to implement D3 charts in react-native (Expo), which will be responsive on both android and ios

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-ios

So I've to implements D3 charts in my project on analytics, have to work on some data related demonstration charts which will be responsive on both platforms.

Any idea will be appreciated...